# How to make recapcha v2 a required field in html form?

Tags: php, html, validation, recaptcha

I'm having issues with adding a recaptcha to my html form.
the widget is displayed and works properly, the problem is the send button is working even when the recaptcha isn't validated. Can someone help me understand what to do to fix this?

I followed the docs on google's guide and all I did was add the following. Is something missing? This is my first ever website so I'm a bit of a noob, could someone tell me if i need to add anything? :')

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
```

```
<form>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback.
Please make a button disabled as a default state.
And then you need to enable it in callback function.

```
    var onloadCallback = function () {
        grecaptcha.render('captacha', {
            'sitekey': '<?php echo $secret_client  ?>',
            'callback': verifyCallback,
            'theme': 'light'
        });
    };
    var verifyCallback = function (response) {
        $('#btn-register').attr('disabled', false);
    };
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer!
I tried adding your script like this
```
<form>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
<script> 
the script you gave me
</script>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>```

But it's not working, i tried sending a message without validating the captcha and it worked :(

Did I add your script in the wrong place or anything? 
thanks a lot for your kind help